# In the "markdown" block, output the result from the "code" block. Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to display the result of the "code" block in the "markdown" block

Write a variable in the "markdown" block, but just the text of the variable name is output.
I tried to create a tag by which we will return to the desired block of code and run it automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: ... are you talking about Jupyter Notebooks? What code? Where?

Answer (score 0):

Markdown usually renders static content, and it is already possible to use both markdown and python code in jupyter.

**The following is a possible workaround:**

Save the code in a python file (*demo01.py*) in the same directory as the jupyter file (*demo01.ipynb*) and link to `demo01.py` using the following format in markdown in jupyter

```
[link to demo1.py](demo01.py)
```

[image]